# Auto-update ->Cinnamon AND Gnome fallback stop working

Tags: 13.04, workspaces, gnome-classic, cinnamon

I'm running 13.04, and work in Cinnamon.  Today, I updated everything that was suggested.  When the update finished, I restarted.  Cinnamon crashed, sending me to gnome fallback.  Gnome fallback worked OK.  I figured I might get cinnamon back by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` just to make sure that everything is at its latest version.

On doing so, Gnome fallback breaks -- specifically, moving to a different workspace leads me to a blank screen (with a mouse) from which I can do nothing.  There are also other bugs -- windows don't get recognized as such when you right click their upper bars (for example, to send them to a different workspace).

I am now working in Unity, in which my productivity is quite bad.

Does this problem sound like a known problem?  Any way to fix besides reinstalling ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get intall cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It help me solve save problem